# Enable "Like/share" buttons under Blogger post

Tags: blogger, blog

I created a blog three years back, and another last year. Both are on [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com) (e.g. myblog.blogspot.com). In the second blog, the social media like/share buttons are by default under every post. (See below.)

[image: like/share buttons]

How could I get that enabled in my older blog?

I couldn’t find any settings for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Blogger Dashboard, go to Layout > Blog Posts (edit), and there is an option for Show Share Buttons.   Turn this on, and the buttons should show.

If they don't, then it's likely that your Post Template is corrupted - the best description I've seen of fixing the problem is here:   http://www.bloggersentral.com/2011/01/reset-corrupted-blog-posts-template.html

There is also another option, which gives you more comprehensive buttons that include counts of times that you post has been liked etc:  it's written up here:  http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/03/putting-facebook-share-this-badge-on.html

Comment: I turned the option ON, it didn't reflected with my existing blogger template. Then I tried another template with existing layout. It worked for me.

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted.   It sounds like the post-template in your original template was corrupted - changing templates overall will have cleared that.